# Generating a 'history' from daily dumps

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a `geometry` table, each row contains a geometry object, could be a line, a point or a polygon. it also contains the `modifyDate` of when it was last modified, `userID` of who last changed it and `itemID`, a unique id for the item.

in the past, every time an item changes, I just overwrote it. I have recently created a separate table called `geometryHistory` so a user can view the changes to an item over time (think a polygon representing an invasive weed).

obviously i can currently only go back a couple of weeks, but I have been taking daily dumps (couple of months missing here and there where the backup was silently failing)

What would be the best way for me to 'generate' this history?

My current thinking is to spin up a test server and import all the dumps into new databases based on date eg `db_2020-12-01`

then creating a new geometry table without a unique key and loading all the tables from the 500+ databases into it then creating some sort of query that will order by `itemID` and `modifyDate` then somehow have it group by `geometry` and `itemID` with `MIN(modifyDate)`

In my mind this should work, but as it is going to be a LOT of work (unless i can script it i guess?) I would like to hear others opinions and whether it is the right direction or if there is a better way.

I know there will be some holes, where an item was changed multiple times in a day or where the backups were not running, but in this case, something is better than nothing.

Comment: If you are using MariaDB-10.3+, or would consider it, [System Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/). Its a solution going forwards. The backup/restore - [MDEV-16029](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16029) has some [code waiting on review](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/818).

Comment: @danblack wow, that looks interesting from a quick glance. will have to look into it more. I am using 10.3 but was actually looking at switching back to mysql at some point due to some major issues i am having with `ST_CENTROID` I was not having with mysql

Comment: Please ensure your `ST_CENTROID` issue is reported, because [the current issues](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22ST_CENTROID%22) don't seem major.

Comment: @danblack reported https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25132